# Deserialize from MemoryStream throws OutOfMemory exception in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, c#-3.0

This is a C# 3.0 Winform problem.

I want to clone a big(not very big actually), complicated object. To do it lazily, I seralize it to a MemoryStream and use BinaryFormatter.UnsafeDeserialize(MemoryStream, null) method to get the cloned object. Inside the UnsafeDeserialize() method, there is always an OutOfMemory exception thrown. The memory should be sufficient.

I read a bit about this as a .net bug but not sure whether it is the case here.

Anyone has any idea why this is happening? Any workround? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a silly question but are you remembering to rewind the MemoryStream to the start of the stream before deserializing it?

It might also help to share some of your code.

Comment: Yes, I set the position to 0 before deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `UnsafeDeserialize` instead of `Deserialize`?

Comment: From MSDN: "In full trust scenarios, UnsafeDeserialize provides better performance than Deserialize."

Comment: Didnt know that!  :)  Now to do that for my stuff!  (although I find it is rather faster already).

Answer (score 1):

What is the object, and how big is it?

I've seen other people with a similar problems, and in some cases switching to a different serializer fixed it. I can suggest several that may be a good fit, depending on the scenario; in particular - is the data a **tree** or a **graph**? (i.e. do child objects ever refer to siblings or their parents? Or just their own children).

Comment: The class is a tree structure.

Comment: Then perhaps consider protobuf-net; it is fast and efficient (space-wise) binary tree serializer. Note that it won't be compatible with existing BinaryFormatter serialized data. Caveat: I'm the author, but it is free; I'm not trying to sell you anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try a FileStream instead, and see how big the file is.

Comment: I have tried that. The file is only 58MB. So it should have no memory problem at all. When the OutOfMemory exception is thrown, the application only uses under 500MB. I have 4G memory and I will assume single .net application uses up to 2G memory.