# OutOfMemory exception from BinaryFormatter.Deserialize coming from its internal StringBuilder call

Tags: c#, deserialization, out-of-memory, stringbuilder, binaryformatter

I have a .NET 4 WCF service that is sending the client some big objects (~115Mb) that get deserialized by the client.  The first time the object comes in it deserializes fine.   However, all subsequent calls throw an `OutOfMemoryException`.  I've checked to make sure that all of my `IDisposables` are wrapped in `using` blocks.  I've looked at the other questions similar to this such as [BinaryFormatter outofmemory exception deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4150721/1300754)
 and [Deserialize from MemoryStream throws OutOfMemory exception in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1136061/1300754)
.  I've tried some of the solutions that people have recommended including using [Simon Hewitt's Optimized Serializer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16017/Optimizing-Serialization-in-NET-part-2).  However, in the end, he still relies on `BinaryFormatter` for deserializing objects.

I caught the `OutOfMemoryException` and looked at the stack trace (see below).  The trace appears to originate from an issue with the memory utilization in the `StringBuilder` class.  I've read other articles about how `StringBuilder` can cause memory problems due to the (length * 2) algorithm they use when more space is needed.

```
at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()    
at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()    
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectString(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)    
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()    
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
```

Is there a way to get `BinaryFormatter` to work differently and not use `StringBuilder` or is there a good alternative to `BinaryFormatter` that manages memory better?

Comment: Was the object of the same size even in the first call? Can you post some code, just in case..

Comment: Yes, it was the exact same response in both cases.  I checked the exact byte size each time to make sure.  I'll see if I can pull some code out, but it is quite lengthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using BinaryFormatter for anything that size (in fact it would probably be a lot smaller if you weren't using binaryformatter). If it is fairly simple data such as tabular data or with some constraints like no circular references and so on, then rolling your own binary serialization with a simple binary writer, or using some off the shelf serializer like [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) or [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com) should be more compact and significantly faster.